# How can I config Open-edX Production Stack SMTP settings?

Tags: edx

I recently just used Vagrant to install the Production Stack of the Open-edX online learning platform. I followed the blog address at this URL http://iambusychangingtheworld.blogspot.ca/2014/03/edx-platform-to-run-cms-at-port-80.html when it came to configuring the ports that the Open-edX platform listens on, and that worked out well.  I would like to thank user Trinh Nguyen.  However I would like to know more about configuring SMTP as well so that when users create accounts they receive their activation email.  This could help anyone just starting Open-edX development including me. It would be good to know about what files need configuring and other important details. Thank you.

Comment: There are some detail at this page : [Enable SMTP for EDX (Production Stack)](https://github.com/CDOT-EDX/ProductionStackDocs/wiki/Enable-SMTP-for-EDX-(Production-Stack))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, after you finish the production stack deployment, the SMTP service will work as desired (can be able to send out emails). And there are something about emails you can do:

- Change the site's domain in the activation email
- ...

And those settings are located at: /edx/app/edxapp , especially these 2 files:

- cms.env.json
- lms.env.json

Hope that will help

Trinh

**Updates:** To sending email via GMail, add the following settings to the common.py:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com' 
EMAIL_PORT = 587 
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'youruser@yourdomain.com' # or youruser@gmail.com 
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'YourPassword' 
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True 
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'you@yourdomain.com'
```

You should restart the edx services, not just the nginx:

**LMS/CMS:**

```
sudo /edx/bin/supervisorctl -c /edx/etc/supervisord.conf restart edxapp:
```

**Workers:**

```
sudo /edx/bin/supervisorctl -c /edx/etc/supervisord.conf restart edxapp_worker:
```

Comment: Hello Trinh could you give an example of the variables that need changing in these files? I have read about changing edx-platform/cms/envs/common.py and setting EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend' rather than console. I was trying to use GMAIL as the SMTP server. How would I be able to do this. I was trying to change the settings in  edx-platform/cms/envs/common.py but this would not work. I tried $ sudo service nginx restart, but that did not help. Thanks again.

Comment: To sending email via GMail, add the following settings to the common.py:

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'youruser@yourdomain.com' # or youruser@gmail.com
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'YourPassword'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'you@yourdomain.com'

You should restart the edx services, not just the nginx:

LMS/CMS - sudo /edx/bin/supervisorctl -c /edx/etc/supervisord.conf restart edxapp:
Workers - sudo /edx/bin/supervisorctl -c /edx/etc/supervisord.conf restart edxapp_worker:

Answer (score 0):

You need next data:

- EMAIL_HOST = "host"
- EMAIL_PORT = 25 or 587
- EMAIL_HOST_USER  = "user"
- EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "*******"
- EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

Optionality you can change some configurations more:

- API_ACCESS_FROM_EMAIL
- API_ACCESS_MANAGER_EMAIL
- BUGS_EMAIL
- BULK_EMAIL_DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
- CONTACT_EMAIL
- DEFAULT_FEEDBACK_EMAIL
- DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
- PAYMENT_SUPPORT_EMAIL
- PRESS_EMAIL
- SERVER_EMAIL
- TECH_SUPPORT_EMAIL
- UNIVERSITY_EMAIL

This are files tha you must change on your installation

- sudo nano /edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/cms/envs/common.py
- sudo nano /edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/lms/envs/aws.py
- sudo nano /edx/app/edxapp/lms.env.json
- sudo nano /edx/app/edxapp/cms.env.json
- sudo nano /edx/app/edxapp/lms.auth.json
- sudo nano /edx/app/edxapp/cms.auth.json

And finally you should run this script:

```
sudo /edx/bin/./supervisorctl restart all
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this answer for anyone using **Juniper**:

The parameters to edit are same but the relevant files are in different location now. You need to edit the following files:

*/edx/etc/lms.yml*

*/edx/etc/studio.yml*

Following are the values to edit:

```
EMAIL_HOST: smtp.gmail.com
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD: YOUR_PASSWORD
EMAIL_HOST_USER: 'YOUR_MAIL@domain.com'
EMAIL_PORT: 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS: true
```

Then restart the following services:

```
sudo /edx/bin/supervisorctl restart lms
sudo /edx/bin/supervisorctl restart cms
sudo /edx/bin/supervisorctl restart edxapp_worker:
```

Note: The following files exist but editing them **do NOT** work anymore:

```
/edx/app/edxapp/lms.env.json
/edx/app/edxapp/cms.env.json
```